# PHP - use of bareword in interface function declarations

Tags: php, interface, bareword

Looking at PHP's documentation about interfaces, specifically here: [PHP: Object Interfaces - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php). The following code is given as a working example. Could someone explain what the bareword 'Baz' being declared as part of the function signature is please?

```
<?php
interface a
{
    public function foo();
}

interface b extends a
{
    public function baz(Baz $baz);
}

// This will work
class c implements b
{
    public function foo()
    {
    }

    public function baz(Baz $baz)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called [*type hinting*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).

The `baz()` method expects the first argument, `$baz`, to be an object of the type `Baz`. An object's type comes from either the class that it is built from, or from an interface that it implements.

Comment: You guys make this too easy. 20 minutes of various searches on google for php function bareword and the like with nothing. Even a response on here telling someone that using a bareword like this is unheard of in programming! A quick post on here, and within 10 minutes... bang! :)

Comment: I probably used hours on my own figuring out and understanding stuff like this. When something is hard won it becomes easy to explain it back.

Comment: Very true indeed. I find things I get very quickly disappear from my knowledge just as quick if they aren't used. I'll remember this one! :)

Answer (score 2):

In the class c, function `baz()` requires a parameter which is a object where it's class `Baz`. `$baz` is just the object name. It's used inside the function of `baz()`.

It's called [Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

> PHP 5 introduces type hinting. Functions are now able to force
>   parameters to be objects (by specifying the name of the class in the
>   function prototype), interfaces, arrays (since PHP 5.1) or callable
>   (since PHP 5.4). However, if NULL is used as the default parameter
>   value, it will be allowed as an argument for any later call.
>
> If class or interface is specified as type hint then all its children
>   or implementations are allowed too.
>
> Type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string.
>   Traits are not allowed either.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) it is called type hinting

Baz is the name of class

and hence the baz method expects the first argument, $baz, to be an object

Comment: Yes, documentation is great when you know what you're looking for! Obviously, I didn't know to look for type hinting. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Cheers @dewd. Hope you got your answer. Make sure to accept the answer whichever you like from all.